# How to open image from MMS in DELPHI XE8

Tags: android, image, delphi, mms, delphi-xe8

I have an application that automatically reads incoming MMS messages.

When he delivers a message with an attachment (picture) so I get the directory where the image is saved:

```
.
.
.
uri:= StrToJURI('content://mms/part');
uriQuery:= StringToJString('mid = 122');
cursor:= SharedActivity.getContentResolver.query(uri, nil, uriQuery, nil, nil);
imgPath:= JStringToString(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJString('_data'))));
.
.
.
```

imgPath is for example: '***/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/app_parts/PART_1440873132846_image.jpeg***'.

When I try to open this file it reports an error: '***Cannot open file - Permission denied***'.

Someone advise me how to open this file (picture from MMS message)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to open a file that belongs to another app.  Android will not usually allow that, unless the other app explicitly shares the file.  Which, in this case, it is apparently not doing.

What you can try instead is using another `content:` URL to access the file based on its ID within the MMS message, rather than its actual file name:

```
uri := StrToJURI('content://mms/part');
uriQuery := StringToJString('mid = 122');
cursor := SharedActivity.getContentResolver.query(uri, nil, uriQuery, nil, nil);
partID := StringToString(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(StringToJString('_id'))));

uri := StrToJURI('content://mms/part/' + partID);
is := SharedActiviy.getContentResolver.openInputStream(uri); // returns a JInputStream 
try
  bitmap := TJBitmapFactory.JavaClass.decodeStream(is); // returns a JBitmap
finally
  is.close;
end;
// use bitmap as needed...
```

Comment: Thanks Remy. You guided me well. It still wants to add a few lines of code and images are loaded. ;)